# Mac os catalina and automount of Linux nfs4 resources

Tags: nfs, automounting, macos

I want to automount all my nfs4 shares in one folder(on Linux and other Unix is really easy).
Using the good old mount works perfect on MacOs Catalina

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,nfsvers=4 slack64:/ /private/nfs/slack64
ls /private/nfs/slack64
backup/  iso/  public/  video/
```

Now I try with the autofs

First edit /etc/auto_master

```
/-                      auto_nfs        -nobrowse,nosuid
```

Then edit /etc/auto_nfs

```
/private/nfs/slack64 -fstype=nfs,nfsvers=4,soft,bg,intr,rw,tcp,resvport nfs://slack64:/
```

after giving `automount -cv`

```
automount: /System/Volumes/Data/home updated (/home -> /System/Volumes/Data/home)
automount: /System/Volumes/Data/Network/Servers updated (/Network -> /System/Volumes/Data/Network)
automount: Conflicting file system object at '/private'.
automount: /System/Volumes/Data/private/nfs/slack64: can't set hidden
automount: /System/Volumes/Data/private/nfs/slack64 mounted (/private -> /System/Volumes/Data/private)
automount: no unmounts
```

The mount is failed!

```
ls /private/nfs/slack64/
ls: cannot open directory '/private/nfs/slack64/': No such file or directory
```

Any help?I have also tried to mount a single share instead of all but no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found

/etc/auto_master contain now

```
/private/nfs            auto_nfs
```

/etc/auto_nfs is like this

```
slack64 -fstype=nfs,nfsvers=4,soft,bg,intr,rw,tcp,resvport slack64:/
```

Redid automount -cv
And all works perfect.
For better help slack64 is the name of Linux nfs4 server

Comment: I couldn't get mine to work. It's not intuitive like on Ubuntu.

Comment: Finally I got mine to work with: `/-                 auto_nfs     -nobrowse,nosuid` and `/etc/auto_nfs:/System/Volumes/Data/Users/me/3TB -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,resvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 nfs://host:/media/me/3TB` . I think there are only certain base paths allowed (which I don't understand properly)